# Authenticate all Request to REST API with no username/password to get any token

Tags: angularjs, node.js, rest, api, authentication

I am selling products, API fetch product from node back-end and show on angular front-end, Back-end is centralized and angular front-end is on multiple domain, I need to authenticate all request made from my angular front-end to node back-end. Users d't have account. I need to make sure no one else copy the product data via POSTMAN or other services. JWT is not working as request are exposed so token can be copied so authentication won't work. I need only my angular front-end can make the request and i can verify the origin of request. Can anyone suggest me what should i try next? Any help will be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe something like checking the originating IP address? You should be able to get the IP in a Node Express backend with something like

```
if (req.ip == 127.0.0.1) // whatever IP your angular app is hosted at
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try whitelisting the front end domains either by CORS properties or use a middleware to check the request url.

Middleware Example

```
var whitelistedURL = ['abc.com','abc.xyz']
function(req, res, next){
    if(whitelistedURL.indexOf(req.originalUrl)==-1){
        res.send({
            status: 'Unauthorised'
        })
    }else{
        next()
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply but req.originalUrl will get you query url like abc.com/test it will return test also the name abc.com can be spoofed by adding x-forwarding header in postman. 
http://expressjs.com/en/api.html#req.originalUrl